# float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'csr_matrix'

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, data-science, k-means

I encountered this problem while trying to plot a cluster on matplotlib.

```
# Training the K-Means model on the dataset
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 4, init = 'k-means++', random_state = 42)

y_kmeans = kmeans.fit_predict(X)


#X.shape is (767135, 37)   (It has undergone One Hot Encoding)

# Visualising the clusters
plt.scatter(X[y_kmeans == 0, 0], X[y_kmeans == 0, 1], s = 50, c = 'red',alpha = 0.3,  label = 'Cluster 1')
plt.scatter(X[y_kmeans == 1, 0], X[y_kmeans == 1, 1], s = 50, c = 'blue',alpha = 0.3, label = 'Cluster 2')
plt.scatter(X[y_kmeans == 2, 0], X[y_kmeans == 2, 1], s = 50, c = 'green',alpha = 0.3, label = 'Cluster 3')
plt.scatter(X[y_kmeans == 3, 0], X[y_kmeans == 3, 1], s = 50, c = 'cyan',alpha = 0.3, label = 'Cluster 4')
plt.scatter(kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 0], kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 1], s = 300, c = 'yellow', label = 'Centroids')
plt.title('Clusters of customers')
plt.xlabel('Nationality')
plt.ylabel('Total Spending')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

While running the code I encounter this error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'csr_matrix'

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: can you include your import statements?

Answer (score 0):

this article on KD Nuggets will show you how to do it as it is a very similar dataset. It even goes as far to show you how to do 3d visualization.

https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/11/customer-segmentation-using-k-means-clustering.html

This challenge uses Age, Gender instead of Nationality ... but the data analysis and method are right on with what you are aiming for.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Now, they're using a 3d plot, but I think this still applies and will fix your matrix problem. Try invoking the scatter plot with these argument types instead of matrices:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
 
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(df.Age[df.label == 0], df["Annual Income (k$)"][df.label == 0], df["Spending Score (1-100)"][df.label == 0], c='blue', s=60)
ax.scatter(df.Age[df.label == 1], df["Annual Income (k$)"][df.label == 1], df["Spending Score (1-100)"][df.label == 1], c='red', s=60)
ax.scatter(df.Age[df.label == 2], df["Annual Income (k$)"][df.label == 2], df["Spending Score (1-100)"][df.label == 2], c='green', s=60)
ax.scatter(df.Age[df.label == 3], df["Annual Income (k$)"][df.label == 3], df["Spending Score (1-100)"][df.label == 3], c='orange', s=60)
ax.scatter(df.Age[df.label == 4], df["Annual Income (k$)"][df.label == 4], df["Spending Score (1-100)"][df.label == 4], c='purple', s=60)
ax.view_init(30, 185)
plt.xlabel("Age")
plt.ylabel("Annual Income (k$)")
ax.set_zlabel('Spending Score (1-100)')
plt.show()
```